# How add ZBarReaderView to viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, zbar-sdk

I try to add ZBarReaderView to my viewcontroller, this is the code I was using

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [ZBarReaderView class];

    readerView = [ZBarReaderView new];
    ZBarImageScanner * scanner = [ZBarImageScanner new];
    [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
                   config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                       to: 0];
    readerView = [readerView initWithImageScanner:scanner];
    readerView.readerDelegate = (id)self;
    readerView.tracksSymbols = YES;
    readerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 3, 320, 400);
    readerView.torchMode = 0;
    [readerView start]; 

    [self.view addSubview:readerView];
}

- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{


    NSLog(@"the image picker is calling successfully %@",info);
    id<NSFastEnumeration> results = [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
    ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
    NSString *hiddenData;
    for(symbol in results)
        hiddenData=[NSString stringWithString:symbol.data];


    NSLog(@"the symbols  is the following %@",symbol.data);


    NSLog(@"BARCODE= %@",symbol.data);

    NSLog(@"SYMBOL : %@",hiddenData);

}
```

I add both  < ZBarReaderDelegate, ZBarReaderViewDelegate >

After scanning the barcode it not reach the Delegate, It just crashed and shows error as

```
[ScanViewController readerView:didReadSymbols:fromImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1cd97b30

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ScanViewController readerView:didReadSymbols:fromImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1cd97b30'
```

How can I add ZBarReaderView to viewcontroller with successful scan can any one help me for this.

Comment: `[ScanViewController readerView:didReadSymbols:fromImage:]:` does not appear in your code...